# Limiting concurrency for a single task across DAG instances

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG (a >> b >> c >> d). This DAG can have up to 100 instances running at a time. It is fine for tasks a, b, and d to run concurrently; however, I would only like one dag_run to run task c at a time. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: `a >> b >> c >> d` means `b` is dependent on task `a` and `b` should wait till task `a` finishes, `c` should wait till `b` ends and so on.  But your description says `a`, `b` and `d` can run concurrently.  are you looking for something like this `[a, b, d] >> c`  or `c >> [a, b, d]`?   tasks in array will run in parallel and `c` should wait until others end or other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Pools](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/pools.html?highlight=pools).

Pools are a classic way of limiting task execution in Airflow. You can assign individual tasks to a specific pool and control how many TaskInstances of that task are running concurrently. In your case, you could create a pool with a single slot, assign task C to this pool, and Airflow should only have one instance of that task running at any given time.